# Dereferencing iterator behavior in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I'm trying to figure out why dereferencing the empty list iterator is preventing the rest of the code from running.   Comment out the line and everything seems fine, but leave it in and the program doesn't seem to get past that point.

I guess it's supposed to be an error since the list is empty, but I'm not getting any warnings or errors.

I'm using codeblocks with MinGW

```
    std::list<std::string> slist;
    std::string word;

    auto iter = slist.begin();

    //what is this doing?
    std::cout << (*iter) << std::endl;

    while(std::cin >> word)
    {
        iter = slist.insert(iter, word);
    }

    slist.insert(slist.begin(), {"foo", "bar"});
    for(auto item: slist)
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
```

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Comment: *but I'm not getting any warnings or errors.* -- Maybe in a debug build that has iterator checking, such as Visual Studio, you will get an error.  But otherwise, C++ does not check and the behavior is undefined.

Comment: If `slist` is an empty list, its `begin()` iterator is equivalent to an `end()` iterator.  Dereferencing an end iterator (better named as "past the end") gives undefined behaviour.   `list` is a library type, so the compiler cannot predict its behaviour (such as what its contents are) that is determined at run time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub also read the articles linked at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Well `std::list` is empty! De-referencing means you are attempting to use something that is not defined. It is just wrong. You should definitely not do that.

You should do instead

```
for (auto i : slist)
   std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

which is safe.